# How to calculate lag between the time log message was generated at application end and the time it was ingested to Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, elastic-stack, opensearch

**Elasticsearch Experts**, need your help to achieve the below mention goal.

**Goal:**

Trying to find a way to calculate lag between the time, log message was generated at application end (**@timestamp** field) and the time, it was ingested to Elastic Search (**ingest_time** field)?

**Current Setup:**

1. I am using FluentD to capture the logs and send to Kafka. Then I use Kafka connect (Elasticsearch connector) to send the logs further to Elasticsearch. Since I have a layer of Kafka in between FluentD and Elasticsearch, I want to calculate the lag between the log message generation time and ingestion time.
2. Log message generation time is stored in timestamp field of the log and is done at when the application generates log. PFB how log message looks at Kafka topic end.

```html
{
  "message": "ServiceResponse - Throwing non 2xx response",
  "log_level": "ERROR",
  "thread_id": "http-nio-9033-exec-21",
  "trace_id": "86d39fbc237ef7f8",
  "user_id": "85355139",
  "tag": "feedaggregator-secondary",
  "@timestamp": "2022-06-18T23:30:06+0530"
}
```

3. I have created an ingest pipeline to add the ingest_time field to every doc inserted to the Elasticsearch index.

```html
PUT _ingest/pipeline/ingest_time
{
  "description": "Add an ingest timestamp",
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "_source.ingest_time",
        "value": "{{_ingest.timestamp}}"
      }
    }]
}
```

4. Once document gets inserted to the index from Kafka using Kafka connect (ES sink connector), this is how my message looks on Kibana in JSON format.

```html
{
  "_index": "feedaggregator-secondary-2022-06-18",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "feedaggregator-secondary-2022-06-18+2+7521337",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
  "thread_id": "http-nio-9033-exec-21",
  "trace_id": "86d39fbc237ef7f8",
  "@timestamp": "2022-06-18T23:30:06+0530",
  "ingest_time": "2022-06-18T18:00:09.038032Z",
  "user_id": "85355139",
  "log_level": "ERROR",
  "tag": "feedaggregator-secondary",
  "message": "ServiceResponse - Throwing non 2xx response"
  },

  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2022-06-18T18:00:06.000Z"
]
  },

"sort": [
  1655574126000
  ]
}
```

5. Now, I wanted to calculate the difference between **@timestamp** field and **ingest_time** field. For this I added a script in the ingest pipeline, which adds a field **lag_seconds** and sets it value as the difference between ingest_time and @timestamp fields.

```html
PUT _ingest/pipeline/calculate_lag
{
  "description": "Add an ingest timestamp and calculate ingest lag",
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "_source.ingest_time",
        "value": "{{_ingest.timestamp}}"
      }
    },
    {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
            if(ctx.containsKey("ingest_time") && ctx.containsKey("@timestamp")) {
              ctx['lag_in_seconds'] = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(ZonedDateTime.parse(ctx['@timestamp']), ZonedDateTime.parse(ctx['ingest_time']))/1000;
            }
        """
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Error:**
But since my **ingest_time** and **@timestamp** fields are in different format it gave error DateTimeParseException.

```html
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "exception",
        "reason": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ScriptException[runtime error]; nested: DateTimeParseException[Text '2022-06-18T23:30:06+0530' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 22];",
        "header": {
          "processor_type": "script"
        }
      }
    ],
    "type": "exception",
    "reason": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ScriptException[runtime error]; nested: DateTimeParseException[Text '2022-06-18T23:30:06+0530' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 22];",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "ScriptException[runtime error]; nested: DateTimeParseException[Text '2022-06-18T23:30:06+0530' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 22];",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "runtime error",
        "script_stack": [
          "java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2049)",
          "java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)",
          "java.base/java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:598)",
          "java.base/java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:583)",
          "ctx['lag_in_seconds'] = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(ZonedDateTime.parse(ctx['@timestamp']), ZonedDateTime.parse(ctx['ingest_time']))/1000;\n            }",
          "                                                                         ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script": "            if(ctx.containsKey(\"ingest_time\") && ctx.containsKey(\"@timestamp\")) {\n              ctx['lag_in_seconds'] = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(ZonedDateTime.parse(ctx['@timestamp']), ZonedDateTime.parse(ctx['ingest_time']))/1000;\n            }",
        "lang": "painless",
        "caused_by": {
          "type": "date_time_parse_exception",
          "reason": "Text '2022-06-18T23:30:06+0530' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 22"
        }
      }
    },
    "header": {
      "processor_type": "script"
    }
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

So, need your help to find the lag_seconds, between the @timestamp and ingest_time fields.

Using managed Elasticsearch by AWS (Opensearch) Elasticsearch Version - 7.1

Comment: That’s very much code. I am not reading through it. Please instead create a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

I can see a Java date parsing problem for the @timestamp field. `ctx['@timestamp']` will return the value "2022-06-18T23:30:06+0530", which is a `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`. You would need to parse this is using `OffsetDateTime.parse(ctx['@timestamp'])`. Alternatively, you could try to access the @timestamp from the fields block. You can read up on date parsing in Java at https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/zoneddatetime-parse/.

Comment: Still easier: `OffsetDateTime.parse(ctx['@timestamp'])`. No need to specify a formatter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I edited the answer to contain this snippet.